# Change caption of a dialogbox when creating the dialog

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Hi i have a dialogbox creating with mfc i want to set his name in initdialog, because i need to load the name from a string table how can i do this thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AfxSetWindowText(CString(IDS_TITLE));
```